# Javascript function using express.js routing

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to javascript, and recently learning the MEAN stack.  I get the gist of how this works, but I don't understand how the module.exports function is using the require function:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
    return app;
};
```

According to the book, it requires the routing file in one argument, and passes it to the express instance 'app'.  Using this logic, you can pass a function to another:

```
var a = function_a();

function_b(...)(a);
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example the file required in the function exported returns a function and that function is invoced immediately passing as its first argument the express app you have created

this could be written like so

```
let createroutes = require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js');
createroutes(app);
```

most probably the `index.server.routes.js` file has a structure like this

```
let express = require("express");
module.exports = (app) => {
  let Controllers = require("./controllers");
  let router = express.Router();
  router.get("/user", Controllers.user)
  app.use("/", router);
}
```

Comment: Ok I get it. I'm passing express as an argument to the function in the required file index.server.routes.js.  I never new you could pass arguments in that way.  Thanks for clearing it up.